# Using member functions within Sench Touch List itemTpl

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, javascript-framework

The documentation about List mention that itemTpl follows the XTemplate syntax.

I would like to use member functions in my itemTpl

If I initialize itemTpl with an XTemplate and that the member function has no argument it works:

```
            items: {
            xtype: 'list',
            store: myStore,
            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<i>{name} {[this.hello()]}</i>', {
                hello: function () {
                    return 'Hello';
                }
            })
```

But as soon as I try to pass an argument (like in the two examples below) it does not work anymore:

```
            items: {
            xtype: 'list',
            store: myStore,
            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<i>{name} {[this.helloWorld(name)}</i>', {
                helloWorld: function (name) {
                    return 'Hello ' + name;
                }
            })


        items: {
            xtype: 'list',
            store: myStore,
            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<i>{name} {name:helloWorld}</i>', {
                helloWorld: function (string) {
                    return 'Hello ' + name;
                }
            })
```

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'fm.helloWorld(values['name'])')

I guess I should not create a new Ext.XTemplate object. Is there any solution to pass the member functions without creating a separate XTemplate?

Or should I give up on the List and build the list myself in the template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
items: {
    xtype: 'list',
    store: myStore,
    itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
         '<i>{name} {[this.helloWorld(values.name)]}</i>', 
         {
             compiled: true,
             helloWorld: function (name) {
                 return 'Hello ' + name;
             }
         })
}
```

your first example would work, with `values.name` instead of just `name`

Answer (score 0):

Use `{[this.helloWorld(name)}`
instead of `{[this.helloWorld(values.name)}`

Comment: if it's inside a string you have to use values.name, as in Adam's answer (ST 2.2)

Answer (score 0):

This usage is also ok:

```
itemTpl :new Ext.XTemplate( '<section class="movieListItem">',
                    '<img src="{UserLogo:this.showLogo}"/>',
                    '<h1>{NickName}</h1>',
                    '<div>{Content}</div>',
                    '</section>',
                    {
                        showLogo:function(value){

                            } 

                });
```